# Curl Drops Parameters

Tags: php, curl

SO, I have been fighting with a piece of code that I want to use to get a remote page's source code using curl.

The code executes successfully, both in the browser and on command line. However, I get the of the main file only. When parameters are added, they are not considered whatsoever in the output.

The Code:
STACK :  Ubuntu, Nginx, PHP-FPM 7.2

```
$urlcontent = 'https://XXX.YYY.COM/file/?var1=value1' ;
// Create a new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

if (!$curl) {
        die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
}

// Set the file URL to fetch through cURL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $urlcontent);

// Set a different user agent string (Googlebot)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'CodiBot/2.1');

// Follow redirects, if any
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Fail the cURL request if response code = 400 (like 404 errors)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

// Return the actual result of the curl result instead of success code
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Wait for 10 seconds to connect, set 0 to wait indefinitely
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

// Execute the cURL request for a maximum of 50 seconds
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);

// Do not check the SSL certificates
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Fetch the URL and save the content in $html variable
$html = curl_exec($curl);

// Check if any error has occurred
if (curl_errno($curl))
{
        echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
        // cURL executed successfully
        print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
        print_r($html);

}
curl_close($curl);
```

PROBLEM

I get the content for `https://XXX.YYY.COM/file` but not the corresponding `?var1=value1` part. IN other words, as I feed info to be retrieved to DB I get only the html of the main file.

I tried :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'foo=1&bar=2&baz=3');
```

I know the remote server may have CORS enabled, but I tried the same url using a remote curl retriever and it succeeded. SO, it may not be the remote server

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to false is a bad idea and doesn't work on modern versions of PHP. Set up your host's certificates properly.

Comment: PHP is not hindered by the same-origin-policy that client-side JavaScript is so CORS is never a problem.

Comment: @Phil Really? I kept thinking it may be the reason?

Comment: _"When parameters are added, they are not considered whatsoever in the output"_  what exactly does this mean? Query parameters are part of the request. What do you expect to see in the response when they are and are not present? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: @Phil When a parameter e.g  "facilityid" is  added, we retrieve its value object from the database and populate it into the page. So, when the parameter is present, the output is dynamically updated than when it is not present